# Open bootstrap Modal from link for each item in a list in view - MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, bootstrap-modal, partial-views

I have a view which does a for each loop over a list of database items. I am looking to have a "Details" action for each one which opens a modal passing the id for each item into it and displays the details for that item in a partial view within that modal.

So far I have the following

```html
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  <a href="#detailsModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Details</a>
}

 <div class="modal fade" id="detailsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                 <div class="modal-content">
                       <div class="modal-body">
@{Html.RenderAction("_PartialDetails", "ActivityAds", new { @id = "NEED TO PASS ID HERE" });}
                       </div>
              </div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

I am trying to avoid putting the modal in the for each loop as I fear that would be very inefficient having to create a modal for every record. I could be calling the partial view in the Modal wrong as well. I am out of practise Im afraid and I am sure there is a way to do this

Thank you

Comment: Like @Nikki9696 said, you only have to define the partial view/modal once and keep it hidden. When details is clicked, you can grab the values you need in JS, bind them to the form, and then show the form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use ajax to fill in the container dynamically.

here is an example from an app i have - note that some of the javascript is in an external js file so can't directly use model; model values are stored in hidden fields and/or data-id, data-value attributes for this purpose

```
        @foreach (var assignment in Model.Assignments)
        {                
            <li role="presentation" id="assignmentsDetails_@assignment.AssignmentView.AssignmentViewId" data-id="@assignment.AssignmentView.AssignmentViewId">
                <a role="menuitem" onclick="selectCriteria(this);" title="@assignment.AssignmentView.AssignmentViewDescription">Criteria @criteriaNumber</a>
            </li>
            criteriaNumber++;
        }
```

javascript

```
function selectCriteria(clickedElement) {
    var dataid = $(clickedElement).parent().attr("data-id");
    loadAssignmentDetails(dataid);
}

function loadAssignmentDetails(assignmentViewId) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: Config.RootUrl + "Assignments/Detail/" + assignmentViewId + "/" + $("#AssignmentTypeValueId").val(),
        success: function (data) {
            $("#assignmentViewDetailsContainer").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This worked with some adjustments and changes. Thank you for the basis. I will add the code Ive used for others if they need it :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution based "Nikki9696" answer :) It works perfectly. Thank you very much! Nikki9696

```js
function showDetails(clickedElement) {
    var dataid = $(clickedElement).attr("data-id");
    showDetailsAjax(dataid);
}

function showDetailsAjax(activityAdID) {
    var link = '@Url.Action("_PartialDetails", "ActivityAds", new { id = "-1"})'
    link = link.replace("-1", activityAdID);

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: link,
        error: function(data)
        {},
        success: function (data) {
            $("#detailsModal .modal-body").html(data);
            $('#detailsModal').modal('show');
        },
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="modal fade" id="detailsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <a onclick="showDetails(this);" id="activityAdDetails_@item.ad_id" data-id="@item.ad_id">Details</a>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternative, similar but different enough that I thought it worth sharing - I wanted to use unobtrusive jquery to achieve the same thing through attribute mark up only, so I define a separate partial view for the modal and it's script, and include it in my layout page, so that in each other view all I need to do is add markup to use the modal and functionality I built into that partial script.  I've added functionality to the modal to allow me to specify a script to call when the modals submit is successful, etc.  The dialog content is retrieved from the server (by calling a controller method that returns a partial view - hence the need to disable ajax cache).  Heres an example outside of a list which calls the javascript RefreshAll when done:

```
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success completeFixtureButton"
          data-submittext="Update" 
          data-modalsubmit="CompleteFixtureForm" 
          data-modaltitle="Fixture Completed"
          data-modalsuccess="RefreshAll();"
          data-modalload="@Url.Action("FixtureCompleted", new { fixtureId = fix.Id })">
```

and here's a similar example but from a link styled as a button instead of a button:

```
  <a class="btn btn-default" href="#"
     data-modalsubmit="editLeagueForm"
     data-modaltitle="Edit Season"
     data-modalsize="lg"
     data-modalload="@Url.Action("EditLeaguePartial", "League", new { leagueId = Model.Season.League.Id, seasonId = Model.Season.Id })"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-white glyphicon-cog"></span>Season Settings</a>
```

Heres one within a list/table:

```
<tbody id="clubList">
  @foreach (Player p in Model.Club.Players.OrderBy(p => p.LastName))
  {
    bool playerManager = Model.Club.Managers.Any(m => m.Id == p.Id);
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href='#' data-modaltitle="@p.FullName" data-modalload="@Url.Action("ContactPlayerPartial", "Player", new { playerId = p.Id })">
          <img src="@Url.Action("ProfilePictureById", "Player", new { playerId = p.Id })" style="max-width:3em; margin-right:10px;" class="pull-left" />  @p.FullName
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    ...
  }
```

and here's the modal partial (_ModalDialogPartial.cshtml) in the Shared Views folder:

```
<div id="details" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h2 id="detailsHeader"></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="detailsBody" ></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="#" id="btnModalCancel" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
                <input type="submit" id="btnModalSave" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

        initialiseModals();
    });

    function initialiseModals() {

      $('#details').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('#details'));
      });

        $(document).on('click', '*[data-modalload]', function () {
            var e = $(this);

            if (e.data('submittext') != undefined) {
              $('#btnModalSave').html(e.data('submittext'));
            } else $('#btnModalSave').html('Save');

            if (e.data('class') != undefined) {
                var cls = e.data('class');
                $('#details').removeClass(cls).addClass(cls);
            }
            if(e.data('modalsize') != undefined) {
              var size = e.data('modalsize');
              $('.modal-dialog').addClass('modal-' + size);
            }

            if (e.data('modalsubmit') == undefined) {
                $('#btnModalSave').hide();
                $('#btnModalCancel').addClass("btn-primary");
            }
            else {
                $('#btnModalSave').show();
                $('#btnModalCancel').removeClass("btn-primary");
                $('#btnModalSave').unbind('click').click(function (ctrl) {
                    $('#btnModalSave').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

                    ctrl.preventDefault();
                    var submitUrl = $('#' + e.data('modalsubmit')).attr("action");

                    var formData = $('#' + e.data('modalsubmit')).serialize();
                    $.post(submitUrl,
                        formData,
                        function (data, status, xhr) {
                            $('#btnModalSave').removeAttr('disabled');
                            $('#details').modal('hide');
                            if (e.data('modalsuccess') != undefined) {
                                eval(e.data('modalsuccess'));
                            }
                        }).error(function () {
                          $('#btnModalSave').prop('disabled', false);
                        });
                });
            }

            $('#detailsBody').load(e.data('modalload'), function () {
                $('#detailsHeader').html(e.data('modaltitle'));
                $('#details').modal('show');
                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('#detailsBody'));
            });
        });
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your solutions. I did consider a partial view dedicated for the modal as I did this myself a few years ago and couldn't remember how I did it successfully. I may try to implement this method as an alternative just for fun and to remind myself. Then choose which is more effiently laid out and understandable ☺thanks for sharing