# How to pass table's current rows fields to a PartalView

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

In my `MVC` view, I am opening a modal dialog which renders a `PartialView` as `RenderAction`. The view is opened when user click `Add` button for the specific row like below.

[image]

From the main view, I want to pass the current row's (select row) ProjectNo, DrawingNo and RevisionNo. Also, preferrably I want to pass this into the respective `ViewBag's` fields. How can I achieve this?

Here is the source code where I am calling the dialog.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Enter Fabrication Information</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div>
                @{Html.RenderAction("Create", "Fabrication", new BPs.Entities.FABRICATION { });}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Update: Adding html for each row

```
@foreach(var info in @Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>info.ProjectNo</td>
        <td>info.DrawingNo</td>
        <td>info.RevisionNo</td>
        <button >Add</button>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: this may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37844621/open-bootstrap-modal-from-link-for-each-item-in-a-list-in-view-mvc

Comment: You need to give more information. Does the html for each row contain data for the `ProjectNo`, `DrawingNo` etc (e.g. as `data-*` attributes). Show what you html for a typical row looks like.

Comment: @StephenMuecke please see the updated question (i added sample of how html of table looks like)

Comment: Assuming your handling the `.click()` event of the button then `var row = $(this).closest (tr);` will get the current row and `row.find (td).eq (0).text();` will get the text of the first cell.

Comment: I got that part now, but how do i send this to my view which is being loaded using RenderAction?

Comment: @WAQ. You have not shown any of the relevant code. You might for example have a hidden input in your modal form for those values - e.g. `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ProjectNo)` and you would set the values - `$('#ProjectNo').val(row.find (td).eq (0).text());`

Answer (score 0):

Bind Add to a jquery event and send values to event function('','') and then open partial view with load function

```
function Add(parameters)
{
    $("<div></div>")
       .addClass("dialog")                        
       .appendTo(".modal-body")
       .dialog({
           title: 'xx',
           close: function () { $(this).remove() },
           closeText: "Close",
           modal: true
       })
       .load("url?"yourparameters);
}
```